# Проблема с импортом executor из библиотеки aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот

```py
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from bot_token import api_token

bot = Bot(api_token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot=bot)
```

*Версия aiogram последняя, импортируется всё кроме executor, ошибка:*

> ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram' (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiogram_*init*_.py)

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: возможные [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ImportError%3A+cannot+import+name+%27executor%27+from+%27aiogram%27)

Comment: "Версия aiogram последняя" https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/index.html#simple-usage

Answer (score 0):

> Версия aiogram последняя

executor был удален из aiogram начиная с третьей версии и выше!
Можете взглянуть на [документацию](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/migration_2_to_3.html%20%D1%84%D1%8B%D0%B2)