aiogram: пишет что не нашел execute
через pip установил aiogram, пытаюсь через команду from aiogram import executor, но он пишет что не нашел такого модуля. В чем может быть проблема?

дубликаты где-то здесь

вот ответ прямо из первого вопроса по приведённой мною ссылке: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1573184/178576

скорее всего проблема в версии aiogram (так как в версии 3 уже нет executor-a).
В таком случае:
$ pip install aiogram==2.14

(или версию старее).
